# I am trying to use the Theme Customization API but I keep getting an error

Tags: api, theme-customizer

This is the error:

> Call to a member function check_capabilities() on a non-object in /home/content/54/11786754/html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-control.php on line 161

and this is my code in the functions.php

```
function lmao_customizer_register($wp_customize) {

$wp_customize->add_section('lmao_colors',  array(

    'title' => __('colors', 'lmao'),
    'description' => 'modify the theme colors'

));



$wp_customize->add_setting('background_color',  array(

    'default' => '#fff',
    'type' => 'option' 

));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'background_color',  array(

    'label' => __('Edit Background Color', 'lmao'),
    'section' => 'lmao_colors',
    'settings' => 'background_color'

) ));

$wp_customize->add_setting('link_color',  array(

    'default' => '#fff',
    'type' => 'option' 

));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'link_color',  array(

    'label' => __('Edit link Color', 'lmao'),
    'section' => 'lmao_colors',
    'settings' => 'link_color'

) ));

$wp_customize->add_setting('link_background_color',  array(

    'default' => '#fff',
    'type' => 'option' 

));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'link_background_color',  array(

    'label' => __('Edit link background Color', 'lmao'),
    'section' => 'lmao_colors',
    'settings' => 'link_background_color'

) ));

$wp_customize->add_setting('link_background_color_hover',  array(

    'default' => '#fff',
    'type' => 'option' 

));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'link_background_color_hover',  array(

    'label' => __('Edit link background hover Color', 'lmao'),
    'section' => 'lmao_colors',
    'settings' => 'link_background_color_hover'

) ));

//start image settings
$wp_customize->add_section('lmao_images',  array(

    'title' => __('Images', 'lmao'),
    'description' => 'modify the theme images'


));

$wp_customize->add_setting('main_image',  array(

    'default' => 'http://hottraxstudioproductions.com/rawr/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/radio-logo.jpg',
    'type' => 'option' 

));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_image_Control($wp_customize, 'main_image',  array(

    'label' => __('Edit main image', 'lmao'),
    'section' => 'lmao_images',
    'settings' => 'main_image'

) ));


    //start copyright settings
$wp_customize->add_section('lmao_copyright',  array(

    'title' => __('Copyright_Details', 'lmao'),
    'description' => 'Edit copyright info'

));

$wp_customize->add_setting('Copyright_Details',  array(

    'default' => 'Copyright',
    'type' => 'option' 

));

$wp_customize->add_control('Copyright_Details',  array(

    'label' => __('Edit copyright info', 'lmao'),
    'section' => 'lmao_copyright',
    'settings' => 'copyright_details'

));



}



function lmao_css_customizer() {
?>

<style type="text/css">

    body { background-color: #<?php echo get_theme_mod('background_color'); ?    >;}

    nav ul li a {

        color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('link_color'); ?>;
        background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('link_background_color'); ?>;


    }

    nav ul li a:hover {

        background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('link_background_color_hover'); ?>;


    }


</style>

<?php



}



add_action('wp_head', 'lmao_css_customizer');
add_action('customize_register', 'LMAO_customizer_register');
```

Please let me know if you need any more information...

Answer (score 1):

I'm still relatively new to Wordpress Development, but shouldn't this code be in customizer.php, in the "inc" folder(which would be within your active theme's folder)?

Also I know the codex says this particular code is just for the live preview, but after adding it in one of my projects it seemed to fix my issue. So you may need to include these get commands for each section you add in the customizer_register function. For instance, before the first bit of your code, try including:

```
function lmao_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'lmao_colors' )->transport='postMessage';
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'testing_customize_register' );
```

Then you would begin with adding the section

```
function lmao_customizer_register($wp_customize) {
    $wp_customize->add_section('lmao_colors',  array(
        'title' => __('colors', 'lmao'),
        'description' => 'modify the theme colors'
));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('background_color',  array(
        'default' => '#fff',
        'type' => 'option' 
));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'background_color',  array(

        'label' => __('Edit Background Color', 'lmao'),
        'section' => 'lmao_colors',
        'settings' => 'background_color'

) ));
}
```

I hope that is helpful. I'm sorry if not, like I said I'm still new myself, but I wanted to try to make an answer, since it seems you've had this question posted for a while now without response.

Best of luck!

Comment: It's not necessary to put this code in the inc folder. It can be included into functions.php in case of a theme from any file anywhere with a require_once etc. I appreciate your effort though :D

Answer (score 0):

Its most probably just a typo.

It's here

```
//start copyright settings
$wp_customize->add_section('lmao_copyright',  array(

'title' => __('Copyright_Details', 'lmao'),
'description' => 'Edit copyright info'

));

$wp_customize->add_setting('Copyright_Details',  array(

'default' => 'Copyright',
'type' => 'option' 

));

$wp_customize->add_control('Copyright_Details',  array(

'label' => __('Edit copyright info', 'lmao'),
'section' => 'lmao_copyright',
'settings' => 'copyright_details'

));
```

Do notice that copyright_details has different case in :

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('Copyright_Details',  array
```

than in settings of add_control section :

```
'settings' => 'copyright_details'
```

Both the settings should be same else the capability error which you got will be triggered.